# How to count the number of lines that start with the word 'the' in python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to get the number of lines that starts with the word "the" in a file

```
def count_the(file_url):
    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    pat = re.search(r'^the', file_url)
    count = 0
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line.startswith('the'):`
            return count += 1
```

Comment: `return count += 1` whaaat? just `count += 1` then return it in the end and no need for regex...

Comment: `return sum(line.startswith('the') for line in r.iter_lines())` should do

Comment: and what if the line starts by "theology" ?

Comment: but theology is a single word, it's not treating the word 'the' as three different characters, it's treating it as a single string

Answer (score 2):

You placed the return in the wrong place, and you can avoid using `re.search` also.

```
def count_the(file_url):
    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    count = 0
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line.startwith('the'):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some serious flaws in your code:

```
def count_the(file_url):
    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
    count = 0
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line.startswith('the'):`
            count += 1
    return count
```

---

1. Remove the `pat` line
2. First count, then `return count` **outside the loop**.